# com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaSerializationException: No LambdaFunction annotation for method hashCode

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I am getting this Error when calling an aws-lambda function from a spring boot project. But when I run my tests, it responds correctly.
Regards.

Full trace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaSerializationException: No
>   LambdaFunction annotation for method hashCode     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   mx.com.dish.dev.drp.monitor.MonitorDRPwebApplication.main(MonitorDRPwebApplication.java:15)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaSerializationException: No
>   LambdaFunction annotation for method hashCode     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaInvokerFactory$LambdaInvocationHandler.validateInterfaceMethod(LambdaInvokerFactory.java:227)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-lambda-1.11.169.jar:na]    at
>   com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaInvokerFactory$LambdaInvocationHandler.invoke(LambdaInvokerFactory.java:213)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-lambda-1.11.169.jar:na]    at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.hashCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.requiresDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.hasApplicableProcessors(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:431)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.requiresDestruction(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1662)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.registerDisposableBeanIfNecessary(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1679)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     ... 17 common
>   frames omitted

Calling code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
 LambdaTestConfig.class
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestMail {

 @Autowired 
 LambaServices service;

 @Test 
 public void testLogin() {
  UserLoginInput login = new UserLoginInput();
  login.setUserName("usuarioPDM");
  login.setPasswordHash(org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex("usrPDM0017#"));
  System.out.println(service.login(login).getOpenIdToken());
 }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code from where you are calling the Lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment lambda functions created using annotations from aws sdk like this one:

```
interface LambdaService {
    @LambdaFunction(functionName = "some-lambda-function")
    fun execute(input: Request): Response
}
```

Catches only invocation of `toString()` method, but not `hashCode()` method.

Spring stores bean in maps, which actively use `hashCode()`.

As a workaround I would suggest using concrete Holder for Lambda Service created with aws sdk:

```
class LambdaServiceHolder(val lambdaService: LambdaService)
```

Then you just create holder bean instead of service bean

```
@Configuration
open class LambdaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    open fun lambdaService(): LambdaServiceHolder {
        val awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.defaultClient()
        val service = LambdaInvokerFactory.builder().lambdaClient(awsLambda).build(LambdaService::class.java)
        return LambdaServiceHolder(service);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully this will be merged soon: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/pull/1591 then you can avoid using an extra holder.